# How do i cycle through different images, Java

Tags: java, animation, textures

My code is used to draw an image onto the screen by g.draw(img);. Is there a way to make the image cycle through different images instead of being static? I've tried .gif files but they don;t work. Here is my code:

```
static BufferedImage img = null;
{
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/textures/bird.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to animate the textures?

Comment: You can use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (*not* java.util.Timer or ScheduledExecutorService, unless you're prepared to use invokeLater to make the image change in the AWT event dispatch thread).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small class to do this for you:

```
public class SimpleImageLoop {

    private final BufferedImage[] frames;
    private int currentFrame;

    public SimpleImageLoop(BufferedImage[] frames) {
        this.frames = frames;
        this.currentFrame = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Moves the loop to the next frame.
     * If we are on the last frame, this loops back to the first
    */
    public void nextFrame() {
        this.currentFrame++;
        if (this.currentFrame >= frames.length) {
            this.currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draws the current frame on the provided graphics context
    */
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.draw(this.frames[this.currentFrame];
    }
}
```

Then you need a simple animation loop to call through `update()` and `draw()`:

```
final SimpleImageLoop imageLoop = new SimpleImageLoop(frames);
while (true) {
    imageLoop.nextFrame();
    imageLoop.draw(g);
}
```

If you need to smooth out the result, you can include additional parameters like how many loops should you perform, the time duration of the frames, etc.

Comment: Well, it's just example code, it can have a few things to be tweaked. What is the problem exactly? Any exception, or just incorrect behaviour?

Comment: I'm extremely new to programing, so i barely know what i'm doing, here is some code (I didn't make it, i'm just working upon it) .http://pastie.org/private/wd1abwpfthij4knttr8zfa How would i implement it into that?

Comment: I did a sample Bird, based on your Bird class: http://pastie.org/10470463 I changed some things to make the class better. Hope with it as a base you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Most probably you will have to make a few changes to make it work together with you other classes. Do you have a specific stack trace?

Comment: No idea what that means. As i said i'm a beginner

Comment: When you try and run your code, does it crash? If it does, you should check the console in you IDE. There should be a log of the error there, together with the stack trace - it basically points to the line of code that caused the exception. You can use it to pin - point problems and deal with them.

Comment: No it's just it makes some code snippets unusable like the one that detects if you hit a pipe.